# Laravel API returns "Unauthenticated"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-authorization

I'm trying to create an api with Laravel Passport following the laravel documentation.

For exemple I create the following route in `api.php`:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/worksheets', 'APIController@worksheets');
```

In the `worksheets` method I have this:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    $records = BO::get();

    return Response::json($records);
} else {
    echo "No auth";
}
```

Now I try to access with Postman with these steps:

1. I obtain the `access_token` doing a POST request to `/oauth/token`
2. I copy the `access_token` and create a GET request.
3. I set the `Authorization` key with `Bearer access_token` and `accept` key with `application/json`.
4. The url is `/api/worksheets`.

This is always the response:

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

I think the problem is in `auth:api` middleware

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Is there any FormRequest that validates your `APIController@worksheets` function? Or else post the whole function.

Comment: Check your auth.php file and you modified your guard properly.

Comment: I post the whole function @BharatGeleda

Comment: I change my guards api driver to passport @MohamedEmad

Comment: @user3242861 Post with the name of the function. The line with `public function worksheets(...` Are you using any FormRequest?

Comment: No @BharatGeleda

Comment: "Unauthenticated" indicates a problem with the authorization credentials. Can you confirm that the *complete* oauth token you receive is being sent with your Authorization header, and it's not being truncated? It's very long and contains word breaks, so it's common to accidentally only copy up to the first period if you double click the string to copy.

Comment: It would also help if you include the specific steps that you followed from the documentation, to rule out (or confirm) a mistake in following the instructions as a cause.